# Expected Value of Random Variables times Indicator Variable

Tags: probability

I have the expression: $E[N \cdot 1_{N \geq n}]$

I am trying to show that this expression is equivalent to $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} kP(N=k)$

Does the following proof suffice?

$E[N \cdot 1_{N \geq n}] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} kP(N=k) \cdot 1_{k \geq n} = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} kP(N=k)$

Comment: This is correct (provided $N$ takes nonnegative integer values only)

Comment: @mge but how do I know this? Since isn't the expected value of an indicator variable the probability of that indicator variable?